# Update list in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

So here is my Data Class

```
data class Bestellung (var id:Int = 0, var anzahl:Int = 1, var speise:String? = null)
```

my List

```
 private var bestellungList = ArrayList<Bestellung>()
```

Trying to update the list if "speise" equals "s" but its not working without any error..

```
  if (bestellungList.contains(Bestellung(speise = s))) {
            var i = bestellungList.indexOf(Bestellung(speise = s))
            bestellungList.set(i, Bestellung(anzahl = +1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is `contains`
pls try this if you want to check first:

```
if(bestellungList.any{ it.speise == "s" }) {
  // do add logic
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thats working but how im getting now the index of it.speise

Comment: @M6Gpower do this: ```bestellungList.indexOfFirst { it.speise == "s" }``` this function will return index of it.speise == s. if no exist, it return -1

Comment: thats also working but if i want to update a value in the existing list , the item will remove complete and then just the value is added to list : bestellungList.set(index, Bestellung(anzahl = +1))

Comment: you mean updating item in list? you can code like this in kotlin: ```bestellungList[index] = Bestellung(anzahl = +1)```. it's simple

Comment: unfortunately this is not working, it replace the item of my list just with a "1", i just want to increment the existing item in the list.

Comment: ah i understood. try this: ```bestellungList[index].speise++```. with speise in model is define as var (not val)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `contains` part. Replace it like this

```
val index = bestellungList.indexOfFirst { 
    it.speise == s
}
if (index >= 0) {
    bestellungList[index] = Bestellung(anzahl = +1)
}
```

Comment: I want to check first , if var s:String is inside the List , if yes then increment anzahl if not .... something else

Comment: That's exactly what this does. By looking for the index, you check if it exists (index >= 0) and only modify if so.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bestellungList.any{ it.speise == "s" }) {
  bestellungList.addAll(Bestellung(anzahl = +1))
} else {
  // handle else statement also
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: Getting a error : Type mismatch: inferred type is Bestellung but Collection<Bestellung> was expected